# How to find and replace a pattern string using sed/perl/awk?

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I have a file foo.properties with contents like

```
foo=bar
# another property
test=true
allNames=alpha:.02,beta:0.25,ph:0.03,delta:1.0,gamma:.5
```

In my script, I need to replace whatever value is against `ph` (The current value is unknown to the bash script) and change it to 0.5. So the the file should look like

```
foo=bar
# another property
test=true
allNames=alpha:.02,beta:0.25,ph:0.5,delta:1.0,gamma:.5
```

I know it can be easily done if the current value is known by using
`sed "s/\,ph\:0.03\,/\,ph\:0.5\,/" foo.properties`
But in my case, I have to actually read the contents against `allNames` and search for the value and then replace within a for loop. Rest all is taken care of but I can't figure out the `sed`/`perl` command for this.
I tried using `sed "s/\,ph\:.*\,/\,ph\:0.5\,/" foo.properties` and some variations but it didn't work.

Comment: is the `0.5` a pre-determined value? or are we supposed to use the value for `gamma` (`.5` in this case)? or is it just coincidence that you mention `0.5` and `gamma` just happens to be the same? will you always be changing the value for field (?) `ph` or could that change from time to time, and if so, could you provide more details on the delimiter(s) for the `alNames` record?

Comment: 0.5 is predetermined. And basically this sed command is part of a script. What I have to do is get the values from a command-line argument something like `my_script.sh --name "ph:0.5,gamma:0.7"` and replace with these values. I think I can take care of the rest by iterating in a loop but can't figure the sed command. I tried `sed "s/\,ph\:.*,/\,ph\:0.5,/"` but it didn't work either. It replaces  subsequent values

Comment: Sorry if my typo of `=` against some values have confused you. Basically this is java properties file with key-value pairs separated by `:` and I need to replace some of them via a bash script.

Comment: @JavaLearner once you accept an answer to this question you asked you should ask a new question about how to do what you describe in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69937434/how-to-find-and-replace-a-pattern-string-using-sed-perl-awk/69942338#comment123628939_69937434) as the correct way to do THAT is NOT going to be to iterate calling the answer to THIS question multiple times in a shell loop, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works with decimal place or not, or no value, anywhere in the line.

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^-_[:alnum:]])ph:[0-9]*(.[0-9]+)?/ph:0.5/g'
```

Or possibly:

```
sed -E 's/(^|[=,[:space:]])ph:[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?/ph:0.5/g'
```

The top one uses "not other naming characters" to describe the character immediately before a name, the bottom one uses delimiter characters (you could add more characters to either). The purpose is to avoid clashing with `other_ph` or `autograph`.

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v new_val="0.5" '
match($0,/,ph:[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
  sub(/:.*/,":",val)
  print substr($0,1,RSTART) val new_val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Detailed Explanation:*** Creating `awk`'s variable named `new_val` which contains new value which needs to put in. In main program of `awk` using `match` function of `awk` to match `,ph:[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` regex in each line, if a match of regex is found then storing that matched value into variable `val`. Then substituting everything from `:` to till end of value in val variable with `:` here. Then printing values as pre requirement of OP(values before matched regex value with val(edited matched value in regex) with new value and rest of line), using next will avoid going further and by mentioning `1` printing rest other lines which are NOT having a matched value in it.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `sub` function of `awk`.

```
awk -v newVal="0.5" '/^allNames=/{sub(/,ph:[^,]*/,",ph:"newVal)} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 5):

A simpler sed solution:

```sh
sed -E 's/([=,]ph:)[0-9.]+/\10.5/g' file

foo=bar
# another property
test=true
allNames=alpha:.02,beta:0.25,ph:0.5,delta:1.0,gamma:.5
```

Here we match `([=,]ph:)` (i.e. `,` or `=` followed by `ph:`) and capture in group #1. This should be followed by 1+ of `[0-9.]` character to natch any number. In replacement we put `\1` back with `0.5`

Answer (score 3):

Would you please try a `perl` solution:

```
perl -pe '
    s/(?<=\bph:)[\d.]+(?=,|$)/0.5/;
' foo.properties
```

- The `-pe` option makes `perl` to read the input line by line, perform
  the operation, then print it as `sed` does.
- The regex `(?<=\bph:)` is a zero-length lookbehind which matches
  the string `ph:` preceded by a word boundary.
- The regex `[\d.]+` will match a decimal number.
- The regex `(?=,|$)` is a zero-length lookahead which matches
  a comma or the end of the string.
- As the lookbehind and the lookahead has zero length, they are not
  substituted by the `s/../../` operator.

**[Edit]**
As Dave Cross comments, the lookahead `(?=,|$)` is unnecessary as long as the input file is correctly formatted.

Comment: I think the lookbehind you use at the end of your regex is unnecessary. The `[\d.]` will stop matching when it gets to a comma or the end of the string anyway.

Comment: @DaveCross thank you for the comment. You are absolutely right. I may have been overthinking.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "\nPerl Starting ... \n\n"; 

while (my $recordLine =<DATA>) 
{
    chomp($recordLine);

    if (index($recordLine, "ph:") != -1) 
    {
       
        $recordLine =~ s/ph:.*?,/ph:0.5,/g; 
        print "recordLine: $recordLine ...\n";

    }
}

print "\nPerl End ... \n\n"; 

__DATA__
foo=bar
# another property
test=true
allNames=alpha:.02,beta:0.25,ph:0.03,delta:1.0,gamma:.5
```

output:

```
Perl Starting ...

recordLine: allNames=alpha:.02,beta:0.25,ph:0.5,delta:1.0,gamma:.5 ...

Perl End ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any sed in any shell on every Unix box (the other sed solutions posted that use `sed -E` require GNU or BSD seds):

a) if `ph:` is never the first tag in the `allNames` list (as shown in your sample input):

```
$ sed 's/\(,ph:\)[^,]*/\10.5/' foo.properties
foo=bar
# another property
test=true
allNames=alpha:.02,beta:0.25,ph:0.5,delta:1.0,gamma:.5
```

b) or if it can be first:

```
$ sed 's/\([,=]ph:\)[^,]*/\10.5/' foo.properties
foo=bar
# another property
test=true
allNames=alpha:.02,beta:0.25,ph:0.5,delta:1.0,gamma:.5
```